# How to set priority for DOM ready blocks?

Tags: jquery, domready

I want to start getting user location if his/her settiings is active. So I check if user setting allows using GPS then I check the allow checkbox using jquery `prop`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //using javascript I check if map settings is active then:
  enableGPS();
})

function enableGPS(){
  $(".activateGPS").prop( "checked", true );
}
```

Uising jquery `prop` I expect the code below to listen and response to changes but it seems not working. Is it because both above and below codes are wrapped inside DOM ready?

How can I pospone the block below to be ready for listening after the blocks above?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.activateGPS').change(function() {
        //Do something with coordinates
    })
})
```

Finally I have to say this is a sample code. Please do not merge the third block into the second block. I want to know how to handle DOM ready blocks proiroties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 stages for DOM loading in js `DOMContentLoaded` (in jQuery `jQuery.ready`) and `window.onload`

The `DOMContentLoaded` event happens on the document object be for the page was loaded.
for example:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

With `window.onload` event on the window object triggers when the whole page is loaded including styles, images and other resources.

> How can I pospone the block below to be ready for listening after the
>   blocks above?

You can listen to the event of the first block the listen to the second and then the third

```
$('#firstBlock').change(function(){
    // do your stuff..
    $('#secondBlock').change(function(){
        // do your stuff..
        $('#thirdBlock').change(function(){
            // do your stuff..
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So should I move the third block inside `window.onload` what if the page has no external resources? is there guarantee that `window.onload` fires after `jquery.ready`? and what if there are more than 2 levels? is'nt there a way to handle multiple `jquery.ready` in their own state? (first state)